# How do I read ftp data into pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for help parsing data from the fbo.gov ftp site.  The link below is an example a daily data feed: ftp://ftp.fbo.gov/FBOFeed20091012

Is there an easy way to parse this data into a pandas dataframe where the leading tags (i.e. AGENCY or URL) are used as columns?

Comment: what does ftp have to do with this?  Reading the data in and constructing a dataframe are two different steps.

Comment: The feed itself is returned as XML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe

Comment: it looks xml-ish, but it isn't valid, so forget about using an xml library.  OP would be better off string grepping whatever data they want out of that doc.

Comment: xavier, I agree.  It is XML'ish, but not perfect.  I tried to parse it using lxml, but recieved XML Syntax errors.