# From a list of files, how to find a list of specific tags with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have a directory of .xml files and I am interested in some specific parts of it, for instance:

```
  <element1>
    <elem1 id="e1" section="1" type="fruit" obj="156" pos="21" str="apple" />
    <elem2 id="e2" section="2" type="fruit" obj="236" pos="11" str="orange" />

    ....

    <elem_N id="N" section="N" type="Animal" obj="7476" pos="7" str="lion" />
  </element1>
```

How can I extract into a pandas dataframe all the tags as columns inside the `element1` tags. Something like this `(*)`:

```
filename, elem id, section, type, obj, pos, str
filename1, elem1, 1, fruit, 156, 21, apple
filename2, elem2, 2, fruit, 236, 11, orange
...
filename_N, elem_N, N, Animal, 7476, 7, lion
```

So far I tried to:

In:

```
import os, glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

input_dir = glob.glob('../XML_FILES/*xml')

for e in input_dir:
    file_name = os.path.basename(e)[:-6] +'.txt'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(e),"lxml")
    element1 = soup.findAll('element1')
    print(file_name,element1)
```

The above code prints: `filename` and the full `elemN` inside a list. However, I do not understand how to transform it into a pandas dataframe. Thus, how can I get `(*)`?

Comment: read this first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach the problem by parsing the files one by one collecting the results into a *list of dictionaries* gathering `elem*` tag names and attribute values along the way. At the end, instantiate a `DataFrame` instance:

```
import glob
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


data = []
for filename in glob.glob('*.xml'):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "lxml")

    for element in soup(re.compile(r"^elem[0-9]+")):
        data.append({**element.attrs, **{'filename': filename, 'elem id': element.name}})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Here is what it outputs when I execute the script:

```
  elem id   filename  id   obj pos section     str    type
0   elem1  input.xml  e1   156  21       1   apple   fruit
1   elem2  input.xml  e2   236  11       2  orange   fruit
2   elem3  input.xml   N  7476   7       N    lion  Animal
```

You can even construct that `data` list in a single line with a *list comprehension*, but this may have a negative impact on the readability of the program:

```
data = [
    {**element.attrs, **{'filename': filename, 'elem id': element.name}}
    for filename in glob.glob('*.xml')
    for element in BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "lxml")(re.compile(r"elem[0-9]+"))
]
```