# convert xml to pandas data framework

Tags: python, xml, pandas, nlp, nltk

i want to convert nps chat corpus in to pandas dataframe. there are 16 xml files

> 10-19-20s_706posts.xml, 10-19-30s_705posts.xml,
>   10-19-40s_686posts.xml, 10-19-adults_706posts.xml,
>   10-24-40s_706posts.xml, 10-26-teens_706posts.xml,
>   11-06-adults_706posts.xml, 11-08-20s_705posts.xml,
>   11-08-40s_706posts.xml, 11-08-adults_705posts.xml,
>   11-08-teens_706posts.xml, 11-09-20s_706posts.xml,
>   11-09-40s_706posts.xml, 11-09-adults_706posts.xml,
>   11-09-teens_706posts.xml

inside nps_chat and i want all to get in to single dataframe.

Here is a sample post from the corpus:

```
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2007 sp1 (http://www.altova.com) by Eric Forsyth (Naval Postgraduate School) -->
<Session xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="postClassPOSTagset.xsd">
    <Posts>
        <Post class="Statement" user="10-19-20sUser7">now im left with this gay name<terminals>
                <t pos="RB" word="now"/>
                <t pos="PRP" word="im"/>
                <t pos="VBD" word="left"/>
                <t pos="IN" word="with"/>
                <t pos="DT" word="this"/>
                <t pos="JJ" word="gay"/>
                <t pos="NN" word="name"/>
            </terminals>
        </Post>
        <Post class="Emotion" user="10-19-20sUser7">:P<terminals>
                <t pos="UH" word=":P"/>
            </terminals>
        </Post>
        <Post class="System" user="10-19-20sUser76">PART<terminals>
                <t pos="VB" word="PART"/>
            </terminals>
```

from this i only need class and relevant text to the pandas framework
for example

```
      Class         text
1     Statement     now im left with this gay name
2     Emotion       :P
3     System        PART
```

i could get text in to pandas using below

```
from nltk.corpus import nps_chat as nps
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
chatroom = nps.posts()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(chatroom),columns=["text"])
```

output
[image]

is there any method to get the class? that is the only missing part

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe

Comment: i tried above. but this seems different as i have to get 16 files instead of 1 xml

Comment: Can't you just loop through the list of files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this ?

```
from nltk.corpus import nps_chat
data = []
for p in nps_chat.xml_posts():
    data.append({"class":p.get("class"), "text": p.text})
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

[image]