# Is XML supported in Watson Studio?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson-studio

I have a collection of different structured XML files that I want to work with in Watson Studio. Is this a supported data type? How could I work with my XML data in the Watson Studio environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can work with XML in Watson Studio using Jupyter Notebooks.

First, you need to make the data available to the service. You can do this by uploading the data directly to your Watson Studio project, programmatically into IBM COS using the API, or access it where it currently is (Amazon S3, Remote Server, etc) by defining a connection to one of these sources.

Once Watson Studio can access the XML data, you can use jupyter to perform your data load, transformation, and analysis - it is likely you will first want to load the XML data into a dataframe - see the following SO answer for details:
[How to convert an XML file to nice pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe)