# python xml file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

I have an xml file in the following format:

```
<table name="ecat">

  <tuple>
    <atom name="TaxAccNo1">test</atom>
    <atom name="TaxAccNo2">00005504</atom>
    <atom name="TaxAccNo3">1</atom>
    <atom name="irn">100107</atom>
  </tuple>

  <tuple>
    <atom name="TaxAccNo1">test</atom>
    <atom name="TaxAccNo2">00005505</atom>
    <atom name="TaxAccNo3">2</atom>
    <atom name="irn">100108</atom>
  </tuple>

  <tuple>
    <atom name="TaxAccNo1">test</atom>
    <atom name="TaxAccNo2">00005506</atom>
    <atom name="TaxAccNo3">3</atom>
    <atom name="irn">100109</atom>
  </tuple>

</table>
```

From this, I want to be able to generate a pandas dataframe that would look like this:

```
    TaxAccNo1   TaxAccNo2   TaxAccNo3   irn 
    test        00005504    1           100107
    test        00005505    2           100108
    test        00005505    3           100109
```

How would I do this?

Comment: check this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I surprised there's no read_xml (the read_html isn't as feature rich as i remember)

Comment: @AndyHayden Exactly, we need it. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use python's xml and a list/dict comprehension:

```
In [11]: import xml

In [12]: e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(open("foo.xml"))

In [13]: pd.DataFrame([{a.get('name'): a.text for a in t} for t in e.findall("tuple")])
Out[13]:
  TaxAccNo1 TaxAccNo2 TaxAccNo3     irn
0      test  00005504         1  100107
1      test  00005505         2  100108
2      test  00005506         3  100109
```