# convert xml data into dataframe

Tags: python, xml

Let's assume that I have an XML like this:

```
<Rules>
       <Set Parameter="4" To="90">
             <If Parameter="1087" EqualsTo="90" />
        </Set>
        <Set Parameter="5" To="-5">
             <If Parameter="1087" EqualsTo="87" />
        </Set>
        <Set Parameter="6" To="[-5,23;36,7;58,7;78,8;94,47]">
             <If Parameter="1087" EqualsTo="87" />
         </Set>
         <Set Parameter="14" To="7,5" />
         <Set Parameter="15" To="-7,5" />
         <Set Parameter="16" To="0,5" />
         <Set Parameter="17" To="3" />
         <Set Parameter="18" To="-3" />
             <If Parameter="1087" EqualsTo="87" />
         </Set>
 </Rules>
```

I would like to read this XML file and convert it to a pandas DataFrame:

```
Parameter<Set>       Parameter<If>
4                     1087
5                     1087
6                     1087
14                    1087
15                    1087
16                    1087
17                    1087
18                    1087
```

This is what I already tried, but I am getting some errors and probably there is a more efficient way of doing this task:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import os

def getMetrics(file_name):
    path="C:\\Users\Z003Z9CF\Downloads"
    os.chdir(path)
    tree = ET.parse('sample1.xml')
    print(tree)
    root = tree.getroot()
    print(root.tag)
    result = []
    for setnode in root.iter('Set'):                         
        node = setnode.attrib["Parameter"]  
        for ifnode in setnode:                              
        if "Parameter" in ifnode.attrib:
            result.append(dict(node=node, parameter=ifnode.attrib.get("Parameter")))
                    return result 

df = pd.DataFrame(getMetrics('sample1.xml'), columns["Parameter","Parameter"])          
print(df)
```

Comment: What type of  `error` you getting? can you show it?

Comment: Getting DF with two columns of Nan's instead of values
        Parameter  Parameter 
         NaN        NaN
         NaN        NaN
         NaN        NaN
         NaN        NaN
         NaN        NaN
         NaN        NaN
         NaN        NaN
         NaN        NaN

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe this one not working... getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you calling method and function return is wrong. You defined the function which accept only one parameter and you sending two. Also shown output as per your `xml` is also wrong.

The output should be as per your `xml`:

```
4                     1087
5                     1087
6                     1087
18                    1087
```

---

Here I debugged and rectified your function mistake on my local setup which is working fine.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


def getMetrics(file_name):
    tree = ET.parse(file_name)
    root = tree.getroot()
    result = []
    for setnode in root.iter('Set'):
        node = setnode.attrib["Parameter"]
        for ifnode in setnode:
            if "Parameter" in ifnode.attrib:
                result.append(dict(node=node, parameter=ifnode.attrib.get("Parameter")))

    return result


df = pd.DataFrame(getMetrics('sample.xml'))
print(df)
```

Your `xml` file, should be look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rules>
    <Set Parameter="4" To="90">
         <If Parameter="1087" EqualsTo="90" />
    </Set>
    <Set Parameter="5" To="-5">
         <If Parameter="1087" EqualsTo="87" />
    </Set>
    <Set Parameter="6" To="[-5,23;36,7;58,7;78,8;94,47]">
         <If Parameter="1087" EqualsTo="87" />
     </Set>
     <Set Parameter="14" To="7,5" />
     <Set Parameter="15" To="-7,5" />
     <Set Parameter="16" To="0,5" />
     <Set Parameter="17" To="3" />
     <Set Parameter="18" To="-3" >
         <If Parameter="1087" EqualsTo="87" />
     </Set>
</Rules>
```

Comment: @praveen does this answer helped you to solve your issue?

Comment: it's working with above xml file... if take large file i'll get error like this.File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 406, column 0

Comment: It probably the issue with your `xml`. Please check it closely. You can validate it from [xmlValidation](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/example/)