# Merge specific arrays and sort them

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, merge

I have opened this large XML file and isolated the dates. I have converted each specific date into an array, but I want to place them into a single array and after that sort them.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

with open('dblp-2020-04-01.xml','r' , encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
   for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if "<year>" in line:

        data = line[6:10]
        data_list = np.array([data])
        print(data_list)
```

The desired output is:

```
['2010']
['2002']
['1992']
['2002']
['1994']
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `np.array` outside of your for-loop and finally append all the dates to it:

```
with open('dblp-2020-04-01.xml', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    data_list = np.array([])
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if "<year>" in line:
            data = line[6:10]
            data_list = np.append(data_list, data)
    print(data_list)
```

And the output will be

```
['2010', '2002', '1992', '2002', '1994']
```

---

Finally, you can sort your array using [`numpy.sort()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
np.sort(data_list) # Ascending order
>>> ['1992', '1994', '2002', '2002', '2010']
```

---

**UPDATE**

Okay so given the scenario you are describing in the comments, I would say that the most efficient way to get a count per date from your XML data, is to [load the XML into a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe) and finally use

```
df['yourDatesColumn'].groupby('yourDatesColumn').count()
```

or

```
df['yourDatesColumn'].value_counts()
```

in order to get the counts per date.

Alternatively, you can choose to create a `pandas.Series` object just for your date column (in case you don't want to load all the data to a pandas Dataframe).

Comment: Thanks a lot!Looks like though the date are way to many and it can't print them.Is there a way I can keep only the first 20 dates?

Comment: @Costas At what point does it get stuck? Before or after sorting the dates?

Comment: @Costas Also, does it fail? It might be the case that your code needs some time to finish..

Comment: before sorting them.(Let me mention the file is 3GB if that might help).

Comment: @Costas Does it fail?

Comment: I dont think so.It doesnt show any unexpected error.It just keeps running.

Comment: @Costas OK. So i think there’s nothing wrong other than it might take some time to complete. You can also verify this by adding a counter in your for-loop and printing it out at each iteration so you can keep track of the execution.

Comment: @Costas In case you want the first 20 dates, you can use inside your for-loop: `if i >= 20: break`

Comment: @Costas Any luck?

Comment: Hi.Looks like the data are approximately 6 million dates so it takes a lot of time to print them.I'll try to have at least a number of those dates.
P.S.The whole idea of the code is to count the times each individual date is being repeated(for example for 2000 we have it 30000 time)

Comment: I really dont want to use an Element Tree cause it will need DTD.