# Convert xml into python panda dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas

Can anyone tell me how do I conver the following xml code into panda dataframe?

```
/Data></Cell></ss:Row><ss:Row><Cell ss:Index="1" ss:MergeDown="0" ss:StyleID="FilaParCentrada"><Data ss:Type="String">26-08-2020</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="2" ss:MergeDown="0" ss:StyleID="FilaParCentrada"><Data ss:Type="String">11-12</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="FilaPar0Decimal"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="4" ss:StyleID="FilaPar1Decimal"><Data ss:Type="Number">60.4</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="FilaPar0Decimal"><Data ss:Type="String">-</Data></Cell><Cell ss:Index="6" ss:StyleID="FilaPar1Decimal"><Data ss:Type="Number">650.3</Data></Cell>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an XML file to nice pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: `beautifulsoup` module is very nice for this