# Parse xml with sub-nodes and create a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml-parsing

I have the following xml format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <run>
      <information>
         <logfile>s.log</logfile>
         <version>33</version>
         <mach>1</mach>
         <problemname>mm1</problemname>
         <timestamp>20201218.165122.053486</timestamp>
      </information>
      <controls>
         <item>VARS</item>
      </controls>
      <result>
         <status>4</status>
         <time>3</time>
         <obj>1.0</obj>
         <gap>0.15</gap>
      </result>
   </run>
</results>
```

I have a sample code below to parse this file after reading this post [How to convert an XML file to nice pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe), but it returns None. However, my question is if there is a fast way to create a dataframe that contains an index from value of  (i.e., VARS) and 4 columns i.e., status, time, obj, and gap.

```
import pandas as pd
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

root = (et.parse('test.xml').getroot()).getchildren()


tags = {"tags":[]}
for elem in root:
    tag = {}
    tag["status"] = elem.attrib['status']
    tag["time"] = elem.attrib['time']
    tag["obj"] = elem.attrib['obj']
    tag["gap"] = elem.attrib['gap']
    tags["tags"]. append(tag)

df_users = pd.DataFrame(tags["tags"])
df_users.head()
```

This is the output I am looking for:

```
      status  time  obj   gap
VARS  4        3    1.0   0.15
```

Comment: What is etree outputting for you? We sort of don't care about the xml, we care about etree's output since that is what you are trying to make a df.

Comment: Also, see [How to convert an XML file to nice pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Your xml isn't well formed - for example, where do `<run>` and `<results>` close?

Comment: @JackFleeting. Thanks. Just updated that.

Comment: @noah Thanks for sharing the post. Updated my question according to that.

Comment: Try to see why are you getting `None`. Is in that there are no `elem` in `root`? If so then it is an xml parsing issue. The code regarding pandas creation should be fast enough as is.

Comment: Can you use lxml instead of xml.etree? It's just simpler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an XML file to nice pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `findall` and `find` methods of `ElementTree` to extract the elements that we need (children of `result` as columns, and `controls/item` as index):

```
pd.DataFrame({x.tag: x.text for x in et.findall('./run/result//')},
             index = [et.find('./run/controls/item').text])
```

Output:

```
     status time  obj   gap
VARS      4    3  1.0  0.15
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you still need to loop through etree to extract bit and pieces using xml.

```
import pandas as pd
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

root = et.parse('test.xml').getroot()

results = []
for ele in eles.findall('run'):
    # assumed each run contains only one control item 
    control = ele.find('controls').find('item').text
    # extract each run result and save it in the results 
    for attr in list(ele.find('result')):
        result = {}
        result['control'] = control
        result[attr.tag] = attr.text
        results.append(result)
# at last, convert into dataframe and set control as index 
results = pd.DataFrame(results)
results = results.set_index('control')
```

Comment: How is "eles" created here?

Answer (score 0):

Note that, status is not under root but you are trying to find it under root.

`status` is under the parent `result`.

You need to check recursively for status under the children.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). It gives detail on the methods with samples. `findall` is useful as others suggested.