# Converting XML file to Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, pandas, dataframe

I have to convert an XML file from a URL link, to a dataframe
I have written the code which gives a dictionary from the XML file. I am not able to convert it into a dataframe. Please suggest if there any other way is suitable for this XML file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml_data=requests.get('http://wbes.nrldc.in/xml/FullSchedule-(130)-19-01-2021.xml')
root = ET.fromstring(xml_data.text)

root = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
data_dict = dict(xmltodict.parse(root))
```

Comment: Maybe this can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem for the data I am using

Comment: OK, what is the problem then? "I am not able to convert it into a dataframe" is not a good problem statement.

Comment: The nested dictionary data_dict = dict(xmltodict.parse(root)) this line is giving, I am not able to understand how do i break it into a DataFrame. I tried converting it into json format, but I think I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Consider parsing data with DOM tools like `etree` (or feature-rich, third-party `lxml`) and then build a list of dictionaries at the repeating `<FullSchedule>` element to be passed into `DataFrame` constructor:

```py
import urllib.request as rq
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

import pandas as pd

url = "https://wbes.nrldc.in/xml/FullSchedule-(184)-30-01-2021.xml"
doc = rq.urlopen(url)
tree = et.fromstring(doc.read())    # NOTE: TAKES SEVERAL MINUTES DUE TO SIZE

data = [{t.tag:t.text.strip() if t.text is not None else None
           for t in fs.findall("*")
        } for fs in tree.findall(".//FullSchedule")]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.shape
# (1152, 21)

df.columns
# Index(['Buyer', 'Seller', 'ScheduleName', 'ScheduleSubTypeName', 'ScheduleDate', 
#        'ScheduleAmount', 'BuyerAmount', 'SellerAmount', 'PocInjectionLoss', 
#        'PocDrawalLoss', 'StateInjectionLoss', 'StateDrawalLoss', 
#        'DiscomInjectionLoss', 'DiscomDrawalLoss', 'Trader', 'LinkName',
#        'OffBarTotal', 'OffBarAllocatedFromPool', 'Open', 'Combined', 
#       'ApprovalNo'], dtype='object')
```

Because `<Buyer>` and `<Seller>` contain nested elements, they are blank above. Hence consider additional parsing and compilation. Only difference above is the `findall` XPath.

```py
data = [{t.tag:t.text.strip() if t.text is not None else None
           for t in fs.findall("*")
        } for fs in tree.findall(".//FullSchedule/Buyer")]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
#          Acronym        ParentState WBESParentStateAcronym
# 0        HARYANA            HARYANA          HARYANA_STATE
# 1      JK&LADAKH  JAMMU AND KASHMIR           JK&LADAKH_UT
# 2          UPPCL      UTTAR PRADESH     UTTARPRADESH_STATE
# 3      JK&LADAKH  JAMMU AND KASHMIR           JK&LADAKH_UT
# 4          UPPCL      UTTAR PRADESH     UTTARPRADESH_STATE
#          ...                ...                    ...
# 1147  CHANDIGARH         CHANDIGARH          CHANDIGARH_UT
# 1148      PUNJAB             PUNJAB           PUNJAB_STATE
# 1149       DELHI              DELHI               DELHI_UT
# 1150     HARYANA            HARYANA          HARYANA_STATE
# 1151  CHANDIGARH         CHANDIGARH          CHANDIGARH_UT

data = [{t.tag:t.text.strip() if t.text is not None else None
           for t in fs.findall("*")
        } for fs in tree.findall(".//FullSchedule/Seller")]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
#        Acronym ParentState WBESParentStateAcronym
# 0       KAMENG        None                   None
# 1         KAPS        None                   None
# 2      VSTPS V        None                   None
# 3      SOLAPUR        None                   None
# 4       LARA-I        None                   None
#        ...         ...                    ...
# 1147      NAPP        None                   None
# 1148    BHAKRA        None                   None
# 1149  CHAMERA3        None                   None
# 1150     RAPPC        None                   None
# 1151    BHAKRA        None                   None
```

---

By the way, `pandas.read_xml()` is in the works by me and uses above algorithm where above may soon be handled with below. *See* [Git issues post](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27554).

```py
url = "https://wbes.nrldc.in/xml/FullSchedule-(184)-30-01-2021.xml"

fs_df = pd.read_xml(url, xpath=".//FullScheule", parser="lxml")
fs_df = pd.read_xml(url, xpath=".//FullScheule", parser="etree")

buyer_df = pd.read_xml(url, xpath=".//FullScheule/Buyer")
seller_df = pd.read_xml(url, xpath=".//FullScheule/Seller")
```