# How to view xml as dataframe in python?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

I have this input.xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <bathrooms>
        <n35237 type="number">1.0</n35237>
        <n32238 type="number">3.0</n32238>
        <n44699 type="number">nan</n44699>
    </bathrooms>
    <price>
        <n35237 type="number">7020000.0</n35237>
        <n32238 type="number">10000000.0</n32238>
        <n44699 type="number">4128000.0</n44699>
    </price>
    <property_id>
        <n35237 type="number">35237.0</n35237>
        <n32238 type="number">32238.0</n32238>
        <n44699 type="number">44699.0</n44699>
    </property_id>
</root>
```

that I would like to analyse as a dataframe. The code I used for this is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def f(elem, result):
    result[elem.tag] = elem.text
    cs = list(elem)
    for c in cs:
        result = f(c, result)
    return result

d = f(root, {})
df=pd.DataFrame(d.items())
print(df)
```

The thing is that the dataframe is nowhere as the xml file. It shows only the last nodes of the xml, because the nodes' names repeat themselves. How can I view all the xml nodes and their correspondent values, without needing to specify the nodes' names? (so that this can be done for any custom xml)

Comment: Please search [the archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe) before asking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an XML file to nice pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259301/how-to-convert-an-xml-file-to-nice-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below steps.

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
df = pdx.read_xml("test.xml", ['first-tag', 'second-tag', 'the-tag-you-want-as-root'])
```

By default, pandas-read-xml will treat the root tag as being the "rows" of the pandas dataframe. If this is not true, pass the argument `root_is_rows=False`

*Sometimes, the XML structure is such that pandas will treat rows vs columns in a way that we think are opposites. For these cases, the `read_xml()` may fail. Try using transpose=True as an argument in such cases. This argument will only affect the reading if `root_is_rows=False` is passed.

source: [https://pypi.org/project/pandas-read-xml/#:~:text=Read%20XML%20as%20pandas%20dataframe,want%20to%20extract%20the%20data.&text=By%20default%2C%20pandas%2Dread%2D,pass%20the%20argument%20root_is_rows%3DFalse%20](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-read-xml/#:%7E:text=Read%20XML%20as%20pandas%20dataframe,want%20to%20extract%20the%20data.&text=By%20default%2C%20pandas%2Dread%2D,pass%20the%20argument%20root_is_rows%3DFalse%20).

Answer (score 0):

Since your intended rows are grandchildren of root, try a nested dictionary comprehension to pass into `DataFrame` constructor. Below casts node text with `float`. Remove if content will not be all decimal point numbers.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Input.xml')

data = {
    node.tag: {i.tag: float(i.text) for i in node.findall("*")}
    for node in tree.findall("*")
}

property_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
property_df
#        bathrooms       price property_id
# n35237       1.0   7020000.0     35237.0
# n32238       3.0  10000000.0     32238.0
# n44699       NaN   4128000.0     44699.0
```